# Internet Recovery loads ML instead of Mavericks

Tags: recovery, internet-recovery

Had to recover my computer using Internet Recovery. For some reason it installed Mountain Lion instead of the Mavericks OS I previously had. How did this happen?

Answer (score 3):

**Internet Recovery will install the OS that came with the Mac**, regardless of whether you updated it at a later date. Once a Mountain Lion is installed, update it it Mavericks through the Mac App Store.